# Mimicking Spring profiles in Guice

Tags: java, guice

In Spring, if I want to have one set of objects for production, and another for local development/testing. I could use the `@Profile` annotation to designate the different classes, and switch between them by providing a system property when starting the app.

Is there anything like this in Guice, or do I need to manually check some property myself and load a different set of modules when bootstrapping my `Injector`?

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak I'm somewhat curious myself...

Comment: @RC Well that's too bad. I saw an oblique reference to the `Stage` enum, but that doesn't seem to be quite as powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to identify the environment yourself, and choose which modules to apply in which environment, but you do have access to [`Modules.override`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Modules.html#override%28com.google.inject.Module...%29) to specifically override certain bindings without having to create a lot of module variants. Use it judiciously—it's very easy to get your modules tangled if you override many bindings or in unpredictable places.